# An email draft I found

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

I found an email draft on my friend's laptop. It was meant to be sent to me. The email has a few different symbols and links that I cannot understand what to make use of it. Can somebody help me decode it?

Here is the screenshot of the email:

[image: wdg3]

Hint 1: I think the process of deciphering the code is to get what is the meaning or deciphering from top to bottom

Comment: Here is the image link transcribed (I vs l is annoying): http://media2.giphy.com/media/N5bT9Ii5twlZS/giphy-preview.webp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this riddle is quite simple:

> I am tired of my work!

The first step is:

> Convert from Wingdings 3 to Plaintext, giving "E ma tevij yh ao qyvc!"

The second step is:

> As the second step suggests @BASH, pass it through the Atbash cipher to get "V nz gverq bs zl jbex!"

Lastly:

> Pass it through ROT13 as the rotation symbol suggests, getting the final answer: "I am tired of my work!"

Comment: Wow you answered all my unanswered questions 

Comment: haha, I'm a fan of ciphers :)